# How to collect all MethodDeclarationSyntax transitively with Roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn

Given a list of `MethodDeclarationSyntax` I would like to collect all the methods in a solution that are calling this method transitively.

I have been using the following code:

```
        var methods = new Stack<MethodDeclarationSyntax>();
        ... // fill methods with original method to start from
        var visited = new HashSet<MethodDeclarationSyntax>();
        while (methods.Count > 0)
        {
            var method = methods.Pop();
            if (!visited.Add(method))
            {
                continue;
            }

            var methodSymbol = (await solution.GetDocument(method.SyntaxTree).GetSemanticModelAsync()).GetDeclaredSymbol(method);
            foreach (var referencer in await SymbolFinder.FindCallersAsync(methodSymbol, solution))
            {
                var callingMethod = (MethodDeclarationSyntax) referencer.CallingSymbol.DeclaringSyntaxReferences[0].GetSyntax();
                methods.Push(callingMethod);
            }
        }
```

The problem is that `MethodDeclarationSyntax` doesn't seem to be a singleton, so this loop is running forever, visiting the same methods again and again.

What is the proper way to uniquely identify a `MethodDeclarationSyntax` in a Dictionary/Hashset?

**Edit 1)**

As a workaround, I'm using the following `MethodDeclarationSyntaxComparer` to initialize my `HashSet`, but it looks very fragile:

```
    private class MethodDeclarationSyntaxComparer: IEqualityComparer<MethodDeclarationSyntax>
    {
        public bool Equals(MethodDeclarationSyntax x, MethodDeclarationSyntax y)
        {
            var xloc = x.GetLocation();
            var yloc = y.GetLocation();
            return xloc.SourceTree.FilePath == yloc.SourceTree.FilePath &&
                   xloc.SourceSpan == yloc.SourceSpan;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(MethodDeclarationSyntax obj)
        {
            var loc = obj.GetLocation();
            return (loc.SourceTree.FilePath.GetHashCode() * 307) ^ loc.SourceSpan.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's about to convert list of `MethodDeclarationSyntax` to the list of coresponding `IMethodSymbol` and then try to find calling `MethodDeclarationSyntax` for all `IMethodSymbol` and keep the relevant `IMethodSymbol` of `MethodDeclarationSyntax` in the list above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm wondering whether using `SyntaxNode` here is the right way to go.

Since you're already using `SymbolFinder` and you're using the semantic model, maybe the right way to go is to actually use `ISymbol`s, rather than `SyntaxNode`s.

`ISymbol` already contains the `SyntaxReference`s you are using, so:

```
   var methods = new Stack<IMethodSymbol>();
    ... // fill methods with original method to start from
    ... // convert methods to symbols via semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol (node);
    var visited = new HashSet<IMethodSymbol>();
    while (methods.Count > 0)
    {
        var method = methods.Pop();
        if (!visited.Add(method))
        {
            continue;
        }

        foreach (var referencer in await SymbolFinder.FindCallersAsync(method, solution))
        {
            var callingMethod = (MethodDeclarationSyntax) referencer.CallingSymbol.DeclaringSyntaxReferences[0].GetSyntax();
            methods.Push(callingMethod);
        }
    }
```

You could possibly make the visited hashset into a `Dictionary<IMethodSymbol, IEnumerable<Location>>`, and concat all the locations, and thus reconstruct the syntaxes from that result.

Comment: Thanks! Just tried and that's indeed a much better approach